# Spring Data MongoDB how to assign expiration time programmatically

Tags: mongodb, spring-data

I couldn't find in any of the Spring-Data documents, what is the way to assign expiration time to a document in MongoDB?

Answer (score 24):

You can do it using `@Indexed` annotation's `expireAfterSeconds` attribute over a field whose type is `Date`.Roughly:

```
@Document
public class SomeEntity {

    String id;

    @Field
    @Indexed(name="someDateFieldIndex", expireAfterSeconds=3600)
    Date someDateField;

   // rest of code here

}
```

Or by manipulating a `MongoTemplate`:

```
mongoTemplate
    .indexOps(SomeEntity.class)
    .ensureIndex(new Index().on("someDateField", Sort.Direction.ASC).expire(3600));
```

Comment: Thanks, but does the whole document is expired and deleted or just the field?

Comment: Its always the whole document

Comment: this does not work. the collection will not be a timeseries.

Answer (score 2):

> Thanks, but does the whole document is expired and deleted or just the
>   field?

According to the MongoDB Documentation https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-ttl/
The TTL index is used to remove documents from a collection.

So, the entire document will be deleted and not uniquely the field indexed.

Nb : The index has to be positioned on a Date Field, else the TTL will not be apply

regards